# Is it possible to position a text label in a layer?

Tags: ios, swift, position, label, layer

I add a sublayer to create pie charts in my swift code. To optimize the view for different devices, I would like to position the text labels which I put on the view in the storyboard in relation to this layer ("build a group").

Is it possible to position labels in a layer? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it's possible. You can create CATextLayer objects and add them as sublayers of your pie chart view's layer.

If you mean is it possible to put UILabel objects inside your layers, then the answer is no. Views can contain layers, but layers can't contain views.